# TCP or UDP for image transfer

Tags: tcp, udp, lwip

I'm using lwip stack on my embedded platform. I have connected the board to my PC via ethernet. My application running on board, dumps the image data out of ethernet. PC applications waits for header, after header it decodes the data and displays the image.

This is for debug purpose only. My images are 4MBytes and i receive 20 Frames per second. So it will be 80MBytes data per second.

Is is advisable to use TCP or UDP?

I tried using TCP, but my send buffers becomes full and it will wait around 200ms to receive acknowledge. Mean time i loose 5-6 images coming from sensor. Can this be fixed if i use UDP?

Thanks,
Sathya

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you apply some kind of compression to your images before sending them to the network.

That said, if you use UDP, you may get better transferrate, but you do need receiving code that can handle lost packets (discard image or request resend or pad affected area)

Comment: Compressed image itself is coming aroung 4MB (MAX). Thanks for your suggestion. Will try if i can handle the lost packets.